# I want to resize my image on smaller screen using nextjs next/image

Tags: css, image, next.js, resize, responsive

I am intended to resize my image on smaller screen. Through following code i am attending the desired sizes but the problem is on smaller screen first image is loaded and render bigger than the desired size and then it re size it self automatically at provided width and height. I want my image to render with the desired size at very first render. My you please help

```
const size = useWindowSize();
    <Grid item xs={12} md={6} textAlign="center">
          {
            size.width < 500 ? <Image
              width={225}
              height={225}
              alt="Picture of the author"
              style={{ borderRadius: "50px" }}
              src={image}
              priority
            /> : <Image
              width={350}
              height={350}
              alt="Picture of the author"
              style={{ borderRadius: "50px" }}
              src={image}
              priority
            />
          }

        </Grid>

**custom hook to get size of the screen**

import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

export default function useWindowSize() {
    // Initialize state with undefined width/height so server and client renders match
    // Learn more here: https://joshwcomeau.com/react/the-perils-of-rehydration/
    const [windowSize, setWindowSize] = useState<any>({
      width: undefined,
      height: undefined,
    });
  
    useEffect(() => {
      // only execute all the code below in client side
      // Handler to call on window resize
      function handleResize() {
        // Set window width/height to state
        setWindowSize({
          width: window.innerWidth,
          height: window.innerHeight,
        });
      }
  
      // Add event listener
      window.addEventListener("resize", handleResize);
  
      // Call handler right away so state gets updated with initial window size
      handleResize();
  
      // Remove event listener on cleanup
      return () => window.removeEventListener("resize", handleResize);
    }, []); // Empty array ensures that effect is only run on mount
    return windowSize;
  }
```